# Java problemDatabase Syntax Error at or near ":"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Im using a PostgreSQL database, and when i'm trying to insert the data, it gives me an error problemDatabase error: ERROR syntax error at or near ":" Position 206.

Here is a code for insert query :

```
public static Model_Customer Insert(String FName, String LName, String Registration, String Make, String Model, String Engine, String Year, String Mileage, String Type, String Date, String Time)  throws Exception {
    try{        
        Statement stmt = Model_Customer.conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO appointment (fname, lname, registration, make, model, engine, year, mileage, type, date, time) VALUES ("+FName+",'"+LName+"','"+Registration+"','"+Make+"','"+Model+"','"+Engine+"','"+Year+"','"+Mileage+"','"+Type+"','"+Date+"',"+Time+") RETURNING appointmentid");
        if(rs.next())
            return Model_Customer.QueryID(rs.getInt(1));

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new Database_Exception(e.getMessage());
        }    
    return null;      
    }
```

In Debug it goes okay to the executeQuery and straight after it, it goes to the catch exception and gives an error. Table and columns in the database are there. There's no ":" anywhere in the code except the messages, so im not sure why it goes like this.

Thanks for your answer Joop Eggen I have used you way and had to add
stmt.executeUpdate(); 
Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Four things to do: 1) Fix your post's formatting so it's readable. 2) Use parameterized SQL. This may well fix your issue anyway, and it'll make it a lot easier to find otherwise. 3) Stop catching `Exception` - and particularly stop then throwing away everything apart from the message. 4) Stop using underscores in your type names. Follow Java naming convnetions.

Comment: I think you should do everything that Jon suggests, your problem will be most likely solved by suggestion no 2. XD

Comment: Argh, probable *SQL INJECTION* hole the size of a small truck. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, http://bobby-tables.com/ . You're lucky you discovered this with a minor error message, not someone hacking your database. Anyway, since you've had success with the approach Joop suggested, please accept his answer; the tick outline below the up/down score arrows.

Comment: Joop's answer is definitely the way to go, but just for the record I think the original error was caused by this: `',"+Time+")`. Time is not quoted and probably contains colons. But please do go with parameterized queries!

Answer (score 2):

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO appointment (fname, lname, registration, make, model, "
        + "engine, year, mileage, type, \"date\", \"time\") "
        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    stmt.setInt(1, FName);
    stmt.setString(2, LName);
    stmt.setString(3, Registration);
    ...
    int updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    if(rs.next())
        return Model_Customer.QueryID(rs.getInt(1));
```

JDBC offers a database engine independent way to retrieve the generated keys: a result set of inserted rows with the generated keys per row.

`RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` is probably not needed. Some field names might be [reserved key words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), which then need double quotes around them.

---

***About recommending PreparedStatement:***

The first remark on every `...+var+...` construed statement, will be: use a prepared statement with `... ? ...`. There are two very important reasons (besides the efficiency of a PreparedStatemen and using BLOBs):

- [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), see [this](http://xkcd.com/327/);
- you can leave out the apostrophes (`'`), and escaping of apostrophe, backslash etcetera is done for you, and you can pass typesafe parameters (int, java.sql.Date).

Comment: cheers i will have a look tonight after work, and get back with result

Comment: Good answer. It'd be nice if you explicitly mentioned the serious security implications of @user3266312's current code, though.

Comment: @CraigRinger I refrained because I was also itching from the non-java-style naming convention, but I assure you, I will be rigorously preaching the Word: be prepared!